# Should I be closing my activities as I go through my app or will this cause Memory Leak? OutOfMemory Errors with drawables in layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am currently developing a game with the android development enviornment. And for the past couple of months I've been dealing with a nasty OOM error. My first problem was that I was placing my drawables in the wrong folder (Drawable-xhdpi in drawable folder). But now, the OOM error eventually happens as you go through the game.

It is a rpg, basically compoed of menus in activity layouts with animations and things. and I've tried everything I could to fix it. I've tried the unbindDrawables method:

```
unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
       view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
       for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
          unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
       }
       ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
 }
```

which does help a lot, but it does not fix the issue. And I cannot use any of the bitmap.factory options or anything, since I load my images through xml in my drawables folder. My images aren't that big by the way, as activities have a background of 720x1280, with some smaller images, and the most total images I'll have on screen at a time is around 8.

So this lead me to think that I may have a memory leak. I did ALOT of research, and I found out that use this(the activity context) will cause a leak, and I should use the application context. However, If I make the switch, there is almost no difference.

So I used MAT to figure out what was going on, and most of my memory is going to `byte[]`, android.graphics.bitmap. And if I drill down to find the cause of this, it seems that java.ref.finalizer is causing all of the retained memory in the VM.

The only reason I could think this is happening, is because whenever I start a new activity I use,

```
Intent fight = new Intent(this, StartScreen.class);
//add this flag to remove all previous activities
fight.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(fight);
finish();
```

which opens a new activity, but closes the one we were just in. So, I'm guessing the bitmaps are not being recycled correctly whenever I finish an activity? or is closing and starting activities like this bad for memory?

I've been on Google all day trying to find the solution to this problem and I can't find it. Any soulutions are appreciated, thank you for reading this!

P.S if you would like to see any snippets of my logcat or code or anything, I am more than happy to post it.

P.S P.S My game has about 10-12 different activities I switch between. For example If I have activities A,B,C I open A, Open B close A, Open C close B, open B close C, open A close B.

**EDIT:** As request about my activities. Usually it is a menu, and when you press a button, that activity finishes, and then moves into another activity. Or buttons will do some math for things like selling, or doing damage to an enemy. One thing about my activity architecture, is that since I am closing every activity as I go to a new one, when I go back to the ones I closed, I am re-creating them. So I don't know if the old activities I finished still have memory in the VM that over time causes the Out Of Memory error, since it all builds up and keeps expanding. I explained My call for a new activity above. And the intent flag closes all past activities (if there are any) in the stack.

**EDIT EDIT:** As per request my oncreate and onDestroy:

OnCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

        //setting fonts
        //a function that binds views by findview by Id and then sets their typeface
        setFont();
        //set up the music service
        //connects the app to the background music service
        playMusic();

        //aquire wakelock
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

OnDestroy:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        //unbinds the service

        unbindService(musicConnection);
        //unbind drawables (function above)
        unbindDrawables((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container));
    }
```

Comment: Writing something about your application architecture, or how and when you open other activities, what happen in those activities might help in solving it.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect this request.

Comment: and if you can post or explain what you handle on onCreate() and onDestroy()methods. secondly what is the reason you manually finish() activities?

Comment: I was manually finishing actvities because I didn't want them in the stack, and in on create they all load things like music, fonts, and get stuff from a save file. And I'll upload an example of my on create and on destroy in a bit

Comment: I added a basic example of my oncreate(some get more complex, but they all contain this basicframework) and an aexample of my OnDestroy(Every activity has the same exact one, except, the make a non static reference call to unbinddrawables from their activity to start screen)

Answer (score 0):

you should destroy the activities that you don't need anymore it takes place in the memory. or if you dont want your user/player to go back to the recent activity you should finish the activity. and if you will notice. if you dont finish the activity and press the back button several times it is layered.

second you mentioned that it is a game. in android programming you need to consider your bitmap resources so to avoid getting an OOM error in your game make use of `sprite sheet` it will save a lot of memory and usage of bitmaps in your application. i encountered those kind of situation and bitmaps mainly causes the OOM error.

Comment: Well honestly, I do come back to the activities. Like for example If I have activities A,B,C I open A, Open B close A, Open C close B, open B close C, open A close B. So that is what I was asking if it is bad practice. and I was looking into that, but I read sprite sheets are bad to use for android games? but if it worked for you, I'll try it out, do you happen have any links you could direct me to? thank you for the answer by the way!

Comment: the benefit that i think you will get from sprite sheets is that instead of having a frame by frame picture of the character or object then store it in a bitmap array, in sprite sheet you could just have only 1 bitmap and 1 image resource. and about the activities if you dont want the user to use the back button you should finish the old activity before starting/opening the new activity. because if you're not finishing the activity and pressed the back button several times you can see that it is layered.

Comment: with the sprite sheet i was using surface view. so the tricky part is using the Rect object in paint() method. it could use a little bit of addition and subtraction.

Comment: Alright cool! I'l definitely look into some sprite sheeting methods for android, since, I do have alot of sprites I'm loading in! And, I am finishing the old activity, it's just I dont want the java.ref.finisher building up my VM memory if I keep opening and closing the same activity you know?

Comment: woah!do you have any article regarding that java.ref.finisher?i didnt know that part when finishing an activity.

Comment: Sadly, no. I don't thats why I am asking on here! but The guy above makes a good point, so I think I'm going to re-order my activity calls to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will say it depends. but with your problem your answer is right [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)
Quick quote from the site

```
   Note: In most cases, you should not explicitly finish an activity using these methods.
As discussed in the following section about the activity lifecycle,the Android 
system manages the life of an activity for you, so you do not need to finish your own
activities. Calling these methods could adversely affect the expected user experience
and should only be used when you absolutely do not want the user to return to this
instance of the activity.
```

Read for more info

well i get you lucidly now, but im thinking of what you are tryna do here, so y dont you use FragmentActivity for B and C.. So, Activity A opens B..B is opened as fragment but works like activity-(thats fragmentActivity), and opens C which is most likely a Fragment..which i think would be perfect for your situation..
for more info about FragmentActivity click [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)
no more activities back and forth.. and its gonna work like an activity..

Comment: Hmmm,I'm a self taught android dev, I never seen that before! I'll definitely try that out, I'll report back if it works. Thank you!

Comment: I just implemented and tested things, out. Where finishing only the activities I was done with ( in the sense that if I had actvities A, B,C It would go A opens B, B opens C,C closes, B closes, A opens B, B opens C etc... However, while this did help, I still got out of memory after a 40MB allocation...

Comment: I now even tried removing all of my finish() calls, and just simple using Intent intent = new intent; intent.addflags(Intent..FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActvivity(intent). But yet I am still getting OOM errors. though with this method I was switching around activites constatnyl for about 10 minutes before it crashed. And the VM was hovering around 35MB, until it reach about 41MB and crashed

Comment: ive editted my answer suggesting what i think might be cooler

Comment: Thank you! I've never used fragments before though, but I'll definitely look into them!